# Cómo obtener los datos de un API con PHP?

Tags: php, html

Quiero obtener la URL y la calidad de los vídeos de esta dirección usando PHP
estoy usando la funcion file_get_contents() pero no me funciona

http://json.zhareiv.com

**Ejemplo:**

```
qualities: {
        "auto":[ {
            "type":"application\/x-mpegURL","url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/cdn\/manifest\/video\/x6ct8p4.m3u8?auth=1517116961-2690-2k41agkl-4bca9b8c660c3ac85ca880acc3badc74"}

        ],"144":[ {
            "type":"application\/x-mpegURL","url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/cdn\/manifest\/video\/x6ct8p4.m3u8?auth=1517116961-2690-2k41agkl-4bca9b8c660c3ac85ca880acc3badc74&include=144"}

        , {
            "type":"video\/mp4","url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/cdn\/H264-176x144-2\/video\/x6ct8p4.mp4?auth=1517116961-2690-laiuifbi-852f0bcfdcccd4207bb8f9292bd192e9"}

        ],"240":[ {
            "type":"application\/x-mpegURL","url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/cdn\/manifest\/video\/x6ct8p4.m3u8?auth=1517116961-2690-2k41agkl-4bca9b8c660c3ac85ca880acc3badc74&include=240"}

        , {
            "type":"video\/mp4","url":"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/cdn\/H264-320x240\/video\/x6ct8p4.mp4?auth=1517116961-2690-pm2nbgpx-a8011dc34f1abd2148d30603d12db34c"}

        ],"380":[ {

}
```

Comment: Según lo que indicas, estas intentando agregar una funciona php en una archivo con extensión html ?

Comment: Muy fácil, haciendo al revés: un archivo PHP con contenido HTML dentro. Y si quieres, puedes hasta crear una URL amigable: `www.tu-url.com/tu-archivo`, sin extensiones, redirigiendo por `.htaccess`, como las URLs de WP.

Comment: si lo se pero otro desarrollador lo hizo con HTML esta parte de su script ya que el no puso Notas ni nada y codigo repatido en muchos archivos y lo que estoy haciendo es al como injeñeria inberza

Comment: Es que una cosa es incluir contenido que sea solamente HTML... y otra cosa es contenido PHP. En este segundo caso, estamos hablando de código que se ejecuta del lado del servidor. Por lo general no es posible, a menos que cambies la configuración de apache, con algo como esto en el `.htaccess` del directorio raíz, o del directorio donde estarán esos `html`: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html`. De todos modos, no es una práctica recomendada, según he leído. Con esa directiva le dices a apache que procese los archivos `htm` o `html` como si fueran archivos `php`.

Comment: tienes razon con esa funcion no es bueno usala pero que hizo el code no uso esa funcion si quieres te paso los archivos para veas como funcione su sistema?

Comment: A ver, las plantillas efectivamente pueden ser .html aunque tenga contenido PHP, luego las servirá un controlador que mediante `ob_start` lo procesa y devuelve, no hay nada de malo en ello si proteges directorios adecuadamente... como el que usa un .tpl vaya... que más dará la extensión del fichero. Lo que no me queda claro es donde está el problema y que error te da...

Comment: como es eso me puedes dar un ejemplo @jonilgz

Comment: No es tan simple como un ejemplo, tienes que tener un "controlador" que gestione todo eso para hacer los replaces etc... que no es algo que se tarde 5 minutos vaya, lamentablemente ahora mismo no dispongo de mucho tiempo como para hacer algo así. Lo que sigo sin entender, es si ya tienes un sistema de replace de variables, para que quieres meter contenido directamente en el HTML, ¿quieres hacer algo como un MVC, pero luego no seguir las directivas?, ¿que sentido tiene entonces?

Comment: es que estoy haciendo un framework para hacer mis trabajos mas rapidos y es por eso que quiero hacer una funcion asi como wordpess para los themes

Comment: Y cuando dices como Wordpress, ¿a que te refieres?, por que no se parece en nada lo que estás haciendo... Tú código más bien parece un patrón MVC (Cosa que Wordpress no cumple). Me explico, por lo que veo que llevas programado y la idea de no usar .php como formato y usar variables que remplazas se acerca más a Smarty por ejemplo, que a Wordpress. Tienes que tener claro el concepto de lo que quieres programar y cómo lo quieres programar, no ir a la batalla y hacer las cosas según vayan surgiendo, esto te ahorrará quebraderos de cabeza. https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: Échale un vistazo al enlace que te dejo, incluso descárgate Smarty y investígalo por dentro ya que se asemeja bastante a lo que tienes en mente.

Comment: Uno esperaría una mejor calidad de preguntas con recompensa... Si estás otorgando puntos, uno creería que al menos investigaste (y se ve reflejado en la pregunta), y se presenta un ejemplo reproducible... Para empezar, los enlaces que estás publicando a los videos no son accesibles... Y, sobre todo, no veo que muestres **qué intentaste hasta ahora**

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "test.php"
                }).done(function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y luego en test.php:

```
<?php
    $return = file_get_contents("http://json.zhareiv.com/");
    echo $return;
    exit();
?>
```

Ahora solo te quedaría realizar el parseo del fichero para sacar los datos que tu quieres.